# Specifing default MaxDegreeOfParallelism cause the parallel loop to run faster

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm using a System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach().
For some reason setting the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to "-1" or even "50", causes the loop to run faster (about 15 seconds and it's consistent).
The default value of the MaxDegreeOfParallelism parameter is -1 and setting it to 50 or any other number should only make it slower.
What can be the reason?

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<FileDataInfo> filesData = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<FileDataInfo>();
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(filesInfo, 
            new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 },
            info =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.FolderPath))
                info.FolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dataPathDirName, info.FolderPath);
            else
                info.FolderPath = dataPathDirName;

            var storageHandler = FileStorageFactory.CreateStorageHander();
            byte[] data = storageHandler.GetFileData(info.FilePath);
            filesData.Add(new FileDataInfo() { Info = info, Data = data });
        });
```

Comment: your last sentence is opposite of your first sentence.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? In one sentence you say it's faster, the next you say it's slower. What are you asking?

Comment: I see no expensive task in your code. parallelizing tasks only works best for expensive tasks, if you try parallelizing lots of small tasks it may negatively affect your performance (or you may get just a little boost which does not worth the complexity your code introduce).

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary GetFileData() is expensive task

Comment: `GetFileData` sounds like an I/O-dominated task. `Parallel.ForEach` isn't a good choice for that - it's designed for CPU-dominated tasks, ideally with no I/O at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not CPU-bound, it is I/O bound. Modern drives can take advantage of a large queue of I/O to perform it more efficiently. By using `Parallel.ForEach`, you're filling this queue up and enabling the drive to perform at its maximum efficiency.

And while you might be noticing a speedup here, it's good to note that you are creating a large amount of threads to accomplish this. Excessive threads is almost never a good idea because it becomes very inefficient due to scheduler overhead and cache churn. If possible, I suggest converting the code to use async and TPL dataflow. This will let you use a single thread to manage a large amount of parallel I/O requests.

Answer (score 2):

`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` tells the TPL how many things can be running at the same time.  This can affect speed of execution in many ways.  By setting this value to a lower value it allows tasks to be running on their own CPU/Core.  This makes things run faster because you're getting good parallelism.  If you set this value higher (or to -1) then you can be running more tasks that CPUs/Cores.  When that happens the time it takes to share the CPU across tasks can take a noticeable amount of time and make the operations look like they are slower.

General rule of thumb: don't set parallelism higher than the number of cores/CPUs in your system.